# How to display listbox items with multi-extended to display items in label?

Tags: vb.net

my homework question is to display the selected items from a listbox (multi-extended) in a label.  I need to display all the selected names in a label.  Please could you help me with the simplest most uncluttered way of doing this.

Thanks!

This is what I've got but it doesn't work.

> ```
> Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
> ```
>
> System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>           ' fills the list box with values
>
> ```
>     namesListBox.Items.Add("Debbie")
>     namesListBox.Items.Add("Bill")
>     namesListBox.Items.Add("Jim")
>     namesListBox.Items.Add("Ahmad")
>     namesListBox.Items.Add("Carol")
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub multiButton_Click(ByVal sender As
> ```
>
> System.Object, ByVal e As
>   System.EventArgs) Handles
>   multiButton.Click
>
> resultLabel.Text = ""
>
> ```
>     Dim name As String = namesListBox.SelectedItems.ToString
>
>     resultLabel.Text = name & ControlChars.NewLine
>
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: WPF, Silverlight, Winforms, Asp.Net, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) property of the ListBox is a collection. You need to iterate the collection.

```
resultLabel.Text = String.Empty
For Each si As Object In namesListBox.SelectedItems
    resultLabel.Text += si.ToString() & ControlChars.NewLine
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the SelectionChanged event

```
Private Sub listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles listBox2.SelectionChanged
    Dim stringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim delimiter = " - "
    For Each item As Object In listBox2.SelectedItems

        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", item, delimiter)
    Next
    label2.Text = stringBuilder.ToString()
End Sub
```